# Extract the Two Or Three Newest Files in a Directory

Tags: r

Just to build on a previous question - [Read the file created/modified last in different directories in R] [Read the file created/modified last in different directories in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921617/read-the-file-created-modified-last-in-different-directories-in-r)

The following code works great to load the most recent file in the directory.

```
files <- list.files(path="Dials/",pattern=".csv",full.names = TRUE,recursive = TRUE)

dirs <- dirname(files)


lastfiles <- tapply(files,dirs,function(v) v[which.max(file.mtime(v))])

today<-read.csv(lastfiles, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

What do I need to do in the second last line of code to get the two or three newest files and rbind them into a single data frame?

Comment: Are you looking for newest file in multiple directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code -

```
files <- list.files(path="Dials/",pattern=".csv",full.names = TRUE,recursive = TRUE)
n <- 3 #3 newest files
selected_files <- files[tail(order(file.mtime(files)), 3)]
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(selected_files, read.csv))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve an array with the name of the files in a directory ordered by modified date using a bash command.

```
>t <- system("ls Dials/ -lt", intern = T)
>sapply(strsplit(t, " ")[-1], function(i) i[9])

[1] "68788203.R"
[2] "dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrTotalCastingLength_8.csv"
[3] "dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrStopperPosFilteredDeviation_8.csv"
[4] "dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrStopperPosFiltered_8.csv"
[5] "dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrStopperPos_8.csv"
[6] "dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrStatus_8.csv"
[7] "dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrPR2Press_8.csv"
[8] "dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrPR1Press_8.csv"
```

You can confirm the files are ordered by modified date by inspecting t

```
> system("ls Dials/ -lt", intern = F)
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 jamoreiras None 551 Aug 15 12:36 68788203.R
-rw-r--r-- 1 jamoreiras None 143 Aug 14 15:02 dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrTotalCastingLength_8.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 jamoreiras None 143 Aug 14 15:02 dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrStopperPosFilteredDeviation_8.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 jamoreiras None 143 Aug 14 15:02 dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrStopperPosFiltered_8.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 jamoreiras None 143 Aug 14 15:01 dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrStopperPos_8.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 jamoreiras None 143 Aug 14 15:01 dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrStatus_8.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 jamoreiras None 143 Aug 14 15:01 dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrPR2Press_8.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 jamoreiras None 143 Aug 14 14:54 dbo_1_STR_PLC8#StrPR1Press_8.csv
```